# Mapping records between databases using identification numbering system

Tags: mysql, replication, synchronization

I have 2 databases, one mySQL database and a SQLite which sycronize back and forth to maintain the same data. To prevent duplicates on either side I was thinking of having a identifcation numbering sytem for records but im not sure how I will go about that?

I need to somehow create a unique ID for records on both databases, for example:

mySQL ===>   data = 1, 5     id=???

sqLITE===>   data = 1, 5     id=???

I need the ID to be the same, so when I syncronize it will not transfer over to the other database.

Another way I thought of is creating a hash between 2 columns in the database, and if the same data is on the other server then it does not syncronize that record of data.

Using a column of the database table as a unique identifier is not suitable in my case.

I'm really not sure how to go about this, so any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question in the way that you need to somehow identify if two rows in two different SQL databases are the same, either because they were independently created or because of an earlier sync.

I think your idea with a hash value is fine. it should do the trick. However, you also could just concatenate the column values in a string and get the same result, maybe with a dash in between in case you have several data columns that would otherwise become ambiguous ("12-2" and "1-12" are then different)

But you still need to send over the generated hash values or concatenated strings of all rows in order to sync. Maybe it makes sense to track rows that are already synced? But then you may need to untrack them if updates of row data values happen.

I am not sure if this answer is helpful to you, because the question leaves many points open to speculation. Can I suggest to make it a bit more clear what you try to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didnt even think of concatanating, its much easier than hashing. Yeah I think you've understood my question, thanks for the help